# SetProperty and property in Jmeter

Tags: apache, testing, jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I need to pass Some variable values from one ThreadGroup to another,

For this I am using

```
${__setProperty(USERNAME, ${USERNAME})}
```

to set username in ThreadGroup1 (I tried to set this value in User defined variable as well as bean assertion) and use

```
${__property(USERNAME)}
```

to fetch this value in ThreadGroup1

but it doesn't work.I set other variables/ properties in same way but they also doesn't seem fetched in ThreadGroup2.

what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter Plugins has Inter-Thread Communication see http://code.google.com/p/jmeter-plugins/wiki/InterThreadCommunication for this purpose.

There are 2 methods to use it:

```
PostProcessor/PreProcessor
Functions __fifoPut and __fifoPop
```

PostProcessor/PreProcessor is easier to use.

Comment: I don't want to use Plugins.

Comment: check this out then http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.jmeter.user/35130

Comment: @Sobia Why? They are very useful.

Comment: They increase load on memory